# TFS trying to check-in bin and obj folders

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After updating to Visual Studio 2012 and TFS online, the pending changes window is always trying to check-in files from the bin and obj folder instead of ignoring them as usual. How can I change this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to "Exclude from Source Control" in VS2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765372/what-happened-to-exclude-from-source-control-in-vs2012)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The referenced thread discusses excluding files *that are part of the solution*.  This question is about bin and obj folders which are typically not included in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the tfs ignore.
see the link for more detail
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore