# TFS file .tfsignore not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I want to exclude the packages folder from being checkedin to my project so I have created a tfsignore using the manual process defined here ([How do I permanently exclude the bin and obj folders from TFS 2012 checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260039/how-do-i-permanently-exclude-the-bin-and-obj-folders-from-tfs-2012-checkin)), for some reason I can't do it using VS as the "Detected Changes" link is not showing on my VS 2012. I have btw, TFS 2012.
When I do this. in the Included changes window, the contents of the Packages folder are still being listed, so the .tfsIgnore file doesn't seem to be working?
Contents of the .TFSIgnore file which is at the root:

```
######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
# 
# Ignore .txt files in this folder 
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\packages
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

Comment: The SO answer that you link to had a typo - using `tfsIgnore` instead of `tfIgnore`.  It's been corrected, thanks!

Comment: I tried that with the change and still didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the file it is looking for is called '.tfignore' (note the lack of an 's').

Comment: This. It is indeed called .tfignore

Comment: Still doesn't work, tried this before also. Do I need to checkin the .tfIgnore file? Does it matter if the file extension is lowercase or doesn't matter?

Comment: I have used this tutorial to add the file using visual stuudio: https://www.appliedis.com/excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your workspace is configured as a local workspace (not server)

Comment: Swapped to local workspace and still the same issue.